# Solution Verification: Convergence of Norms $\implies$ Convergence of Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, self-learning, solution-verification

I found the following exercise in *Bartle*'s *Elements of Real Analysis*. I'm learning on my own and have a couple of doubts would love it if someone could take a look. ($\left|{\left|{x}\right|}\right|$ represents the standard Euclidean norm).

> Let $X = (x_n)$ be a sequence in $\Bbb R^p$ and let $\lim ( \left|{
>  \left|{x_n }\right|}\right| ) = 0$. Show that $\lim (x_n) = 0$.
>   However give an example in $\Bbb R$ to show that the convergence of
>   $(\left|{x_n}\right|)$ may not imply the convergence of $(x_n)$

**This is my attempt:**

*Solution Part 1:* $$\left|{ \left|{ x_n - 0 }\right| }\right| = \left|{\left|{x_n }\right|}\right| = \left|{\left|{x_n }\right|}\right| - 0 = \left| \ {\left|{\left| { x_n }\right|}\right| - 0} \ \right| $$ Therefore given any $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is an  $m \in \Bbb N$ such that $n \ge m \implies \left|{ \left|{ x_n - 0 }\right| }\right| = \left| \ {\left|{\left| { x_n }\right|}\right| - 0} \ \right| \lt \epsilon $. Therefore $\lim (x_n) = 0$.

*Solution Part 2:* The counter-example I came up with was $(a_n) = \left({ (-1)^n \left[{ 3 + \frac 1 n}\right]  }\right)$. Since $\left|{a_n}\right| = \left|{3 + \frac 1 n}\right| = 3 + \frac 1 n $, it can be proven that $\lim (\left|{a_n}\right|) = 3$. Now to prove that $(a_n)$ diverges:

Suppose it converges to a limit $l \in \Bbb R$. Let $\epsilon = 1 \gt 0 $. Then there is $m \in \Bbb N$ such that $m \ge n \implies \left|{a_n - l}\right| \lt 1$. Let $m_1$ and $m_2$ be two respectively odd and even natural numbers greater than or equal to $m$. Then,

$$ \left|{a_{m_1} - l}\right|, \left|{a_{m_2} - l}\right| \lt 1 \implies \left|{\left ( -\frac 1 {m_1} - 3\right) - l}\right| \lt 1 \;\; \text { and } \;\; \left|{\left(3 + \frac 1 {m_2}\right) - l}\right| \lt 1 $$

Adding the two inequalities we have $$ \left|{ 2l - \left({ \frac 1 {m_2} - \frac 1 {m_1}}\right) }\right| \lt 2 \implies 2 \left|{l }\right| \lt 2 + \frac 1 {m_1} + \frac {1}{m_2} \lt 2 + \frac 2 m \implies \left|{l}\right| \lt 1 + \frac  1 m$$

Now say we pick $\epsilon = \frac 1 {m}$. Then,

$$\left|{a_n - l}\right| \ge \left|{a_n}\right| - \left|{l}\right| \gt \left|{a_n}\right| - \left(1 + \frac 1 m\right) \gt 3 - \left(1 + \frac 1 m\right)  = 2 - \frac 1 m \ge \frac 1 m  \;\;\; \forall n \in \Bbb N \rightarrow\leftarrow $$

I have a couple of doubts and would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out:

$Q_1:$ Well I'm not sure how to prove the divergence of a sequence so am not sure about the proof of the non-existence of the limit in *Part 2*. Is it good enough? Is there a better way? If so guide me..

$Q_2:$ *Part 1* does not stipulate the fact that $p \gt 1$. It generally shows for any Cartesian space $\Bbb R^p$ the convergence of the norms of the elements in the sequence implies convergence of the sequence. Then how come we have a counter-example in $\Bbb R$??

Comment: I've been sick the last couple of days.  Ping me if you'd still like to take a look at this again -  after a cursory glance, it looks like Jlamprong has answered all your questions.

Comment: @Jason DeVito - Oh Sorry for bothering you. Hope you're better now. Well yes for the most part. Maybe just a look at my own answer at the bottom??

Comment: Looks good to me.  There's a general theorem from which everything follows:  If a sequence $a_n$ converges to $L$, then any subsequence also converges to $L$.  (This is not too hard to prove.)  Contrapositively, if a sequence has two subsequences which converge to different limits, then the sequence itself diverges.  Now, given your sequence $a_n = (-1)^n$, the subsequence $a_{2n}$ obviously converges to $1$ while the subsequence $a_{2n+1}$ obviously converges to $-1$, so you're done by this theorem.

Comment: @Jason DeVito: Thanks a lot for taking a look. Greatly appreciated. Yeah that theorem is coming up soon. Think I get the relationship. Hope you are feeling better. And thanks again for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. It is an alternative counterexample: take $a_n=(-1)^n$, then we have $\|x_n\|\to 1$ but $\{x_n\}$ is divergent. Why? Assume $\{x_n\}$ is convergent to $x$. Put $\epsilon=\frac{\|1-x\|+\|1+x\|}{2}>0$. Since $x_n$ is convergent then there exists $N$ such that $\|x_n-x\|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. However, taking $n=2N$ and $n=2N+1$ gives $\|x_{2N}-x\|=\|1-x\|$ while  $\|x_{2N+1}-x\|=\|-1-x\|=\|1+x\|$ that is impossible both of them less that $\epsilon$
. So, $\{x_n\}$ is divergent.

Q2. In the Part1, the sequence has to be converged to $0$. If not, the implication will not work.

Comment: $Q_2$ is sorted. Can't believe I overlooked the condition. But although I know about Cauchy sequences superficially I am required to prove this without it. And What do you think? Any dents in my proof?

Comment: Why did you choose two different values of $\epsilon$? Let have a look the definition of convergent sequence
$x_n\to x$ iff for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $\|x_n-x\|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. This means that $x_n$ is divergent iff for every $x$, $x_n$ is not convergent to $x$ which is equivalent to say that there exists $\epsilon_0>0$ such that there exists a sequence of natural numbers $n_i$ such that $\|x_{n_i}-x\|>\epsilon_0$.

please look my edit

Comment: Isn't that what I have proven?? Yeah I guess it looks a little ugly. Well I chose $l$ arbitrarily. If the sequence converges then I found a bound for $l$ and showed it does not work for another value of $\epsilon$.

Comment: You can do a little bit change in your proof using what I did in my edit

Comment: Thanks loads for the help. Think I grasped it now. Even posted my own answer. Much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

This counter-example for *part 2* in the above question is courtesy @Jlamprong but I think I have an easier way to prove its divergence and I'm posting it as an answer mainly for the community to check if its valid.

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in $\Bbb R$ defined by $a_n= (-1)^n$. Suppose it converges to a limit $a$. Let $\epsilon = \frac 1 2. $ Then there is $m \in \Bbb N$ such that $n \ge m \implies \left|{ a_n - a }\right| \lt \frac 1 2.$ Without loss of generality assume $m$ is even. Then $\left|{a_m - a}\right| = \left|{1 - a}\right| \lt \frac 1 2 \implies a \in ( \frac 1 2 , \frac 3 2 )$. But then; $$\left|{a_{m + 1} - a}\right| = \left|{-1 -a}\right| = \left|{a + 1}\right| = a + 1 \gt \frac 1 2 \Rightarrow\Leftarrow$$